# Distorted sound and low volume on wired headphones on Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

The sound is low and distorted (as if it was clipped) when using any wired (mini-jack) headphones on Ubuntu 23.10.

There's no problem when the sound is coming out of main speakers or bluetooth headphones or USB headphones.

The problem is the same coming from any audio player BUT there's no problem when testing from the Audio panel of Kubuntu System Settings. When I click on the Test button and then "Front Left", the sound is loud and clear.

When setting SMPLayer to Mono mode, the sound becomes clear but stays very low (even with all volumes at max).

I have not configured anything on my audio system (so it's the default config and packages) and I'm the only one using my computer.

The problem appears to have started sometime around January 24th 2024. Among the packages upgrade during the 3 weeks before, only two could have been involved in the bug (according to GPT-4):

- `linux-firmware`
- `libfluidsynth3`

I've tried (to no avail):

- With several well-functioning headphones.
- Checking and adjusting volumes in `alsamixer`
- Checking and adjusting volumes in `pavucontrol`
- Resetting Alsa config (reinstall with purge).
- Downgrading the `libfluidsynth3` package to its previous version (2.3.3-2.1)
- Downgrading the Linux kernel version to 6.5.0-14 (currently, it is the 6.5.0-15).
- Uninstalling (with purge) Pipewire to use only Pulseaudio.

I haven't tried downgrading `linux-firmware` because I'm afraid it could break my system.

Also, when considering removing the package `libfluidsynth3` (which I haven't done, for fear of breaking my audio even more), `apt remove` indicated that it would also remove the package `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad`. It may be noteworthy because in the description of this package, there is the note "GStreamer Bad Plug-ins is a set of plug-ins that aren't up to par compared to the rest. They might be close to being good quality, but they're missing something - be it a good code review, some documentation, a set of tests, a real live maintainer, or some actual wide use."

The issue looks similar to this one : https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=287068, apart from the fact that mine is only on wired headphones. Also, they say the bug has been fixed on the 6.5 kernel.

Machine: Laptop Lenovo Legion Y730-17ICH

```
$ inxi -A
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Cannon Lake PCH cAVS driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: NVIDIA GP107GL High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  API: ALSA v: k6.5.0-15-generic status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PipeWire v: 0.3.79 status: active
```

```
$ pactl info
Server String: /run/user/1000/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 35
Server Protocol Version: 35
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 290
Tile Size: 65472
Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.79)
Server Version: 15.0.0
Default Sample Specification: float32le 2ch 48000Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
Default Source: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
Cookie: a227:b242
```

```
$ pactl list cards
Card #43
        Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1
        Driver: alsa
        Owner Module: n/a
        Properties:
                api.acp.auto-port = "false"
                api.acp.auto-profile = "false"
                api.alsa.card = "1"
                api.alsa.card.longname = "HDA NVidia at 0x94000000 irq 17"
                api.alsa.card.name = "HDA NVidia"
                api.alsa.path = "hw:1"
                api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
                api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio1"
                device.api = "alsa"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
                device.description = "GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller"
                device.enum.api = "udev"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-analog-pci"
                device.name = "alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1"
                device.nick = "HDA NVidia"
                device.plugged.usec = "4591546"
                device.product.id = "0x0fb9"
                device.product.name = "GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller"
                device.subsystem = "sound"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1"
                device.vendor.id = "0x10de"
                device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
                media.class = "Audio/Device"
                factory.id = "14"
                client.id = "34"
                object.id = "43"
                object.serial = "43"
                object.path = "alsa:pcm:1"
                alsa.card = "1"
                alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0x94000000 irq 17"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                device.string = "1"
        Profiles:
                off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
                output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5900, available: no)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: no)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: no)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 800, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 800, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
                pro-audio: Pro Audio (sinks: 4, sources: 0, priority: 1, available: yes)
        Active Profile: off
        Ports:
                hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (type: HDMI, priority: 5900, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 1, not available)
                        Properties:
                                port.type = "hdmi"
                                port.availability-group = "Legacy 1"
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                                card.profile.port = "0"
                        Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo, output:hdmi-surround, output:hdmi-surround71
                hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (type: HDMI, priority: 5800, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 2, not available)
                        Properties:
                                port.type = "hdmi"
                                port.availability-group = "Legacy 2"
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                                card.profile.port = "1"
                        Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra1, output:hdmi-surround-extra1, output:hdmi-surround71-extra1
                hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (type: HDMI, priority: 5700, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 3, not available)
                        Properties:
                                port.type = "hdmi"
                                port.availability-group = "Legacy 3"
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                                card.profile.port = "2"
                        Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra2, output:hdmi-surround-extra2, output:hdmi-surround71-extra2
                hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (type: HDMI, priority: 5600, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 4, not available)
                        Properties:
                                port.type = "hdmi"
                                port.availability-group = "Legacy 4"
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                                card.profile.port = "3"
                        Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra3, output:hdmi-surround-extra3, output:hdmi-surround71-extra3

Card #44
        Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3
        Driver: alsa
        Owner Module: n/a
        Properties:
                api.acp.auto-port = "false"
                api.acp.auto-profile = "false"
                api.alsa.card = "0"
                api.alsa.card.longname = "HDA Intel PCH at 0x94518000 irq 152"
                api.alsa.card.name = "HDA Intel PCH"
                api.alsa.path = "hw:0"
                api.alsa.use-acp = "true"
                api.dbus.ReserveDevice1 = "Audio0"
                device.api = "alsa"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
                device.description = "Built-in Audio"
                device.enum.api = "udev"
                device.form_factor = "internal"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-analog-pci"
                device.name = "alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3"
                device.nick = "HDA Intel PCH"
                device.plugged.usec = "4652966"
                device.product.id = "0xa348"
                device.product.name = "Cannon Lake PCH cAVS"
                device.subsystem = "sound"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
                device.vendor.id = "0x8086"
                device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
                media.class = "Audio/Device"
                factory.id = "14"
                client.id = "34"
                object.id = "44"
                object.serial = "44"
                object.path = "alsa:pcm:0"
                alsa.card = "0"
                alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0x94518000 irq 152"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                device.string = "0"
        Profiles:
                off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
                output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 6565, available: yes)
                output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 6500, available: yes)
                output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5965, available: no)
                output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5900, available: no)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5765, available: no)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5765, available: no)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: no)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 865, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 865, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 800, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 800, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 665, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 665, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 665, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 665, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
                input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority: 65, available: yes)
                pro-audio: Pro Audio (sinks: 4, sources: 1, priority: 1, available: yes)
        Active Profile: output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        Ports:
                analog-input-internal-mic: Internal Microphone (type: Mic, priority: 8900, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 1, availability unknown)
                        Properties:
                                port.type = "mic"
                                port.availability-group = "Legacy 1"
                                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
                                card.profile.port = "0"
                        Part of profile(s): input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-stereo-extra1+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround-extra1+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71-extra1+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-stereo-extra2+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround-extra2+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71-extra2+input:analog-stereo
                analog-input-mic: Microphone (type: Mic, priority: 8700, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 2, not available)
                        Properties:
                                port.type = "mic"
                                port.availability-group = "Legacy 2"
                                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
                                card.profile.port = "1"
                        Part of profile(s): input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-stereo-extra1+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround-extra1+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71-extra1+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-stereo-extra2+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround-extra2+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71-extra2+input:analog-stereo
                analog-output-speaker: Speakers (type: Speaker, priority: 10000, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 3, availability unknown)
                        Properties:
                                port.type = "speaker"
                                port.availability-group = "Legacy 3"
                                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
                                card.profile.port = "2"
                        Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
                analog-output-headphones: Headphones (type: Headphones, priority: 9900, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 4, not available)
                        Properties:
                                port.type = "headphones"
                                port.availability-group = "Legacy 4"
                                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
                                card.profile.port = "3"
                        Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
                hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (type: HDMI, priority: 5900, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 5, not available)
                        Properties:
                                port.type = "hdmi"
                                port.availability-group = "Legacy 5"
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                                card.profile.port = "4"
                        Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo, output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround, output:hdmi-surround+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71, output:hdmi-surround71+input:analog-stereo
                hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (type: HDMI, priority: 5800, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 6, not available)
                        Properties:
                                port.type = "hdmi"
                                port.availability-group = "Legacy 6"
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                                card.profile.port = "5"
                        Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra1, output:hdmi-stereo-extra1+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround-extra1, output:hdmi-surround-extra1+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71-extra1, output:hdmi-surround71-extra1+input:analog-stereo
                hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (type: HDMI, priority: 5700, latency offset: 0 usec, availability group: Legacy 7, not available)
                        Properties:
                                port.type = "hdmi"
                                port.availability-group = "Legacy 7"
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                                card.profile.port = "6"
                        Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra2, output:hdmi-stereo-extra2+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround-extra2, output:hdmi-surround-extra2+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71-extra2, output:hdmi-surround71-extra2+input:analog-stereo
```

Comment: Did you accidentally plug the headphones into the line out port, or do anything to reconfigure the speaker port to act as a line out port?

Comment: There only one mini-jack plug on my laptop, for headphones. I have not reconfigured anything on my audio system and I'm the only one using my computer. I don't even know what a `line out` port is (I've just looked it up) so I don't know where to check. But thank you for your question: I've updated my question to mention that it's the default audio config.